# C# .NET Core plugin dll loader

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I have a .NET core web API, where I have several plugins (class library .dll files). I want to load these files on startup, and it was working correctly, but now I need to change the project structure.

Previously, upon building all the files (the web API and the plugin .dll files) were placed in the following directory: `...\bin\Debug\net6.0`. But now I want to have a configuration file for each plugin, for example `config.json`, which is loaded separately in each plugin.

So the structure I had in mind was:
`...\bin\Debug\net6.0`, which still contains all the web API files, and then inside of that directory a directory called `Plugins`, and in that directory a folder for each plugin that exists, which is named the same as the plugin, and it contains the plugin .dll and it's corresponding `config.json` file.

A simple way to do this, and get around all the troubleshooting would be to just leave all the files inside of the `...\bin\Debug\net6.0` directory, and name the config files the same as the plugin file, so they are "unique", but I would like to improve on that, if possible.

I have some progress by doing this:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Plugins\Plugin1\Plugin1.csproj">
    <DestinationSubDirectory>Plugins\Plugin1\</DestinationSubDirectory>
</ProjectReference>
```

Doing this for each plugin it does the job of putting inside of `...\bin\Debug\net6.0\Plugins\name\`, but it does not include the config file, and it also throws the error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Plugin1, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

Is there a good approach to do this, or should I stick to the "dumb" approach of having all the plugins inside of the root build directory and having config files named the same as the plugin?

Comment: When its a projectreference why is it called plugin? When hearing the word plugin i would have expected something loaded dynamically at runtime. This way its just like any assembly referenced at compile time. We can't really help with the configfile without infos. Is it part of the project and the "Copy to Output Directory" property is correctly set?

Comment: You can add a post-build event to copy the plugin DLL and its corresponding configuration file to the "Plugins" directory.